# Why does my Angular site return a directory when published to IIS?

Tags: javascript, angular, web, iis

I have been attempting to publish an Angular app to a Windows server using IIS. When the site opens, it returns a directory rather than the site itself. If I click on index.html, the site displays as expected.

What am I doing wrong?

[image: Screenshot (website, index.html, web.config)]

Comment: If you didn't enable default document for index.html, then rewrite to "/" will just return the directory listing.  You have to enable default document and make sure it is loading page form index.html. Otherwise, you'd better rewrite your URL to "index.html" instead of "/" directly.

Comment: Thank you! That solved it. I'm in a bit over my head.

By enabling default document instead of using URL Rewrite like all of the tutorials, will I be losing out on any features?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help others who have this issue. I would like to post the answer here.

When we deploy angular application in IIS, no handler is required. When means extensionless request will not be handled automatically. So we use default document to specify the application entry and then rewrite no file no directory URL to this entry.

This is how we deploy angular js in IIS.

extension less URL=>rewrite => /=> default document=>index.html.

So both URL rewrite and default document should be required. And you won't lose out on any feature.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate you taking the time to respond.